# Convert Row with duplicate values to Column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'A' that looks something like:

```
_______________________________________________________________
|query_id |   query      |  response   |user_response_count    |
|--------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   1     |   acne       |   BothBad   |       2               |
|   1     |   acne       |  BothGood   |       1               |
|   2     |   asthma     |   BothBad   |       1               |
|   2     |   asthma     |   product 1 |       1               |
|   2     |   asthma     |   BothGood  |       1               |
|   3     |   bell palsy |   product 2 |       2               |
|   3     |   bell palsy |   BothGood  |       1               |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query to get something that looks like:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________
| query_id |   query   |   BothGood   |   BothBad   |   Product 1 |   Product 2   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |    acne   |         1    |    2        |       0     |         0     |
|    2     |   asthma  |         1    |    1        |       1     |         0     |
|    3     | bell palsy|         1    |    0        |       0     |         2     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That "user_response_count" column actually says, 2 users selected "BothBad" option for "acne" query.

I know, by using `max`, I can change my rows to the column, but here it would be difficult to the max. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation:

```
select query_id, query,
       sum(case when response = 'BothGood' then cnt else 0 end) as BothGood,
       sum(case when response = 'BothBad' then cnt else 0 end) as BothBad,
       sum(case when response = 'product 1' then cnt else 0 end) as product1,
       sum(case when response = 'product 2' then cnt else 0 end) as product2
from a
group by query_id, query;
```

Comment: Thanks for your query. The problem is I don't get 2 count for "acne" query and "BothBad". Similary, I don't get 2 count for "bell palsy" query and "Product 2". In both the cases, I get 1.

Comment: Actually, I am not looking for count of "BothGood" or "BothBad" or "Product". That count column is actually says, 2 users selected "BothBad" option for "acne" query.

Comment: @Achal . . . You seem to want the `sum()` rather than just the count of rows.

Comment: With the sample data, we could achieve an equivalent result with `MAX()` in place of `SUM()`.  I suspect that SUM() is what we're after, but the specification is a little loose. What should be returned when there are multiple rows with same query_id, query and response

Comment: There won't be any case when multiple rows with the same query_id, query, and response will be returned. But, the updated query worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `conditional aggregation` as

```
select query_id, query,
   max( coalesce(case when response = 'BothGood'  then user_response_count end,0) ) 
     as BothGood,
   max( coalesce(case when response = 'BothBad'   then user_response_count end,0) ) 
     as BothBad,
   max( coalesce(case when response = 'product 1' then user_response_count end,0) ) 
     as Product_1,
   max( coalesce(case when response = 'product 2' then user_response_count end,0) ) 
    as Product_2
  from tableA
 group by query_id, query
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac5b4370d7185dc9cd36a16bec5ff995)</kbd>

Comment: Actually, I am not looking for count of "BothGood" or "BothBad" or "Product". That count column is actually says, 2 users selected "BothBad" option for "acne" query.

Comment: @Achal well, due to last edits, you seem to looking for `user_response_count`